# Sencha setActiveItem carousel - slide only goes to the left

Tags: sencha-touch

So Im setting some buttons to slide a carousel.

```
preezer.setActiveItem(this.text, "slide");
```

Its working just fine EXCEPT that I would sure love it if it would slide the way that the card should go... in other words, if a user clicks the 3rd button it slides left to the 3rd card but if then the user clicks the first button, I would rather it slide right back to card #1.

Anyone know how to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put some conditional logic and define the slide directions

```
if(preezer.getActiveItem()..) {
    preezer.setActiveItem(this.text,{type:'slide',direction:'right'});
}
```

Comment: That would work except that I am building these buttons dynamically and was using a property name rather than the index... I suppose if I used the index then I could compare the two and move direction based on that.... thanks!